# Required field validation issues in ASP.Net grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a text box in grid view control,i used required field validator to validate the textbox like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Relationship" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
     <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRelationShip" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RelationShip") %>' Visible="false" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRelationShip" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRelationShip" ForeColor="Red" ClientIDMode="AutoID"
                ErrorMessage="Please enter relationship" ValidationGroup="vgUpdateRelationShip" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRelationShipUpdate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgUpdateRelationShip"></asp:LinkButton>                            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have many rows in my grid view , when i edit and update the text box value if single text box is empty it shows error in all text box.
How to resolve this problem, i want if single text box is empty shows error only in single text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the `ValidationGroup` is unique per row, like `ValidationGroup='<%# "ValidationGroup_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
          ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup='<%# "ValidationGroup_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" ValidationGroup='<%# "ValidationGroup_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Update</asp:LinkButton>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```